# Is there a URL that will allow users to open a survey (in it's own dialog box) without having to click the "Respond to Survey" button?

Tags: 2010, url, survey

I know that right clicking in the survey itself and selecting "Properties" provides the URL for the survey, but this opens the survey as a page. I'd like the URL to open the survey in its own dialogue box in the same way it does when "Respond to Survey" is clicked. Is there a non-code way to do this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WITHOUT CODE:**

I always send them straight to the New Form for surveys:

`http://sharepoint/site/Lists/SurveyName/NewForm.aspx`

**WITH CODE:**

```
<script>
    function openDialog(){
        var options = {
            title: "Fill out survey",
            url: "http://sharepoint/site/Lists/survey/newform.aspx",
            width: 800,
            height: 500
        };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openDialog();">Take Survey</a><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too. It opens the survey as a full page. Do you know how to open a survey in its own dialogue box (in the same way it is presented when clicking the "Respond to Survey" button?

Comment: Not without code

Comment: If you've any HTML suggestions that I can place in a CEWP - that I can do.